# transformación xls a html

Tags: html, xml, xsl, xslt

Estoy realizando una transformacion de xml a html:
Archivo xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type=" html/xsl" href="tarea5.xsl"?>
<artistas>
  <artista cod="a101">
    <nombreCompleto>Diego Velázquez</nombreCompleto>
    <nacimiento>1599</nacimiento>
    <fallecimiento>1660</fallecimiento>
    <pais>España</pais>
    <fichaCompleta>https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Vel%C3%A1zquez</fichaCompleta>
  </artista>
  <artista cod="a102">
    <nombreCompleto>Michelangelo Caravaggio</nombreCompleto>
    <nacimiento>1571</nacimiento>
    <pais>Italia</pais>
    <fichaCompleta>https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caravaggio</fichaCompleta>
  </artista>
  <artista cod="a103">
    <nombreCompleto>Herrada de Landsberg</nombreCompleto>
    <nacimiento>1125</nacimiento>
    <fallecimiento>1195</fallecimiento>
    <pais>Alsacia</pais>
    <fichaCompleta>  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herrada_de_Landsberg</fichaCompleta>
  </artista>
  <artista cod="a104">
    <nombreCompleto>Francisco de Goya</nombreCompleto>
    <nacimiento>1746</nacimiento>
    <fallecimiento>1828</fallecimiento>
    <pais>España</pais>
    <fichaCompleta>https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_de_Goya</fichaCompleta>
  </artista>
</artistas>
```

El archivo xsl funciona bien pero necesito transformar la columna Página web del archivo html resultante, quiero que aparezca el texto "Saber más" pero conserve el link que me lleva a wikipedia:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <!-- TODO customize transformation rules 
         syntax recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt 
    -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Lista de artistas</title>  
                <style type="text/css">
                    .azul1{background-color:#4dbbff;}
                    .azul2{background-color:#a4d6ff;}                   
                    td{text-align: center;}
                    h2{color:#001bfe; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;}
                </style>           
            </head>
            <body>
                <div style="float:left; position:absolute; width:100%;">
                    <h2>Lista de artistas</h2>
                    <table border="2" align="center">                        
                
                        <tr class="azul1">
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Año de nacimiento</th>
                            <th>Año de fallecimiento</th>
                            <th>Pais</th>
                            <th>Página web</th>                                             
                        </tr>    
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="./artistas/artista">
                            <xsl:sort select="nacimiento"> 
                            </xsl:sort>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>    
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="artista">
           
        <xsl:if test="./nacimiento>'1500'">
            
            <tr class="azul2">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@cod"/></td>                
                <td><xsl:value-of select="nombreCompleto"/></td>                
                <td><xsl:value-of select="nacimiento"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="fallecimiento"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="pais"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="fichaCompleta"/></td>           
            </tr>      
        </xsl:if>    
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

El problema lo tengo porque quiero que en la columna página web me aparezca el texto "Saber más" y contenga el link correspondiente a wikipedia pero sin que se muestre.
Adjunto cómo deberia quedarme el html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Tabla de artistas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Año de nacimiento</th>
        <th>Año de fallecimiento</th>
        <th>País</th>
        <th>Página web</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a102</td>
        <td>Michelangelo Caravaggio</td>
        <td>1571</td>
        <td>Desconicido</td>
        <td>Italia</td>
        <td>
          <a target="blank" href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caravaggio">Saber más</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a101</td>
        <td>Diego Velázquez</td>
        <td>1599</td>
        <td>1660</td>
        <td>España</td>
        <td>
          <a target="blank" href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Vel%C3%A1zquez">Saber más</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a104</td>
        <td>Francisco de Goya</td>
        <td>1746</td>
        <td>1828</td>
        <td>España</td>
        <td>
          <a target="blank" href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_de_Goya">Saber más</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Se le ocurre a alguien cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: <td><xsl:value-of select="fichaCompleta"/></td>     cambialo a  <td><a href="{<xsl:value-of select="fichaCompleta"/>}"/><td>

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero me aparece el siguiente error justo en esa línea:  The value of attribute "href" associated with an element type "a" must not contain the '<' character. [53]      Creo que tiene dos /> y alguna de ellas debe sobrar

Comment: ¿Puede ser que haga falta una etiqueta de cierre </a>?

Comment: Pues alli juega un poco con las etiquetas, la verdad hace mucho que no hago un xsl pero la idea es esa y recuerdo que funcionaba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final el código que funciona es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <!-- TODO customize transformation rules 
         syntax recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt 
    -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Lista de artistas por Rafael Pérez</title>  
                <style type="text/css">
                    .azul1{background-color:#4dbbff;}
                    .azul2{background-color:#a4d6ff;}                   
                    td{text-align: center;}
                    h2{color:#001bfe; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;}
                </style>           
            </head>
            <body>
                <div style="float:left; position:absolute; width:100%;">
                    <h2>Lista de artistas</h2>
                    <table border="2" align="center">                        
                
                        <tr class="azul1">
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Año de nacimiento</th>
                            <th>Año de fallecimiento</th>
                            <th>Pais</th>
                            <th>Página web</th>                                             
                        </tr>    
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="./artistas/artista">
                            <xsl:sort select="nacimiento"> 
                            </xsl:sort>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>    
                                   
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="artista">
           
        <xsl:if test="./nacimiento>'1500'">           
            <tr class="azul2">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@cod"/>
                </td>                
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="nombreCompleto"/>
                </td>                
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="nacimiento"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fallecimiento"/>
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="pais"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a target="blank">
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of select="fichaCompleta"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        Saber más                        
                    </a>
                </td> 
            </tr>      
        </xsl:if>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Podrías cortarlo un poco utilizando `<a target="blank" href="{fichaCompleta}">Saber más</a>` en lugar  de `xsl:attribute`.